# Swapping between video cards on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, vgaswitcheroo, dual-graphics

With Ubuntu 16.04, fglrx and Catalyst Center is no more. How can I change my primary video card on dual graphic systems like Intel/AMD or AMD/AMD. Is there a script for this, or a good manual?

**Update 1**: I found a manual about `vgaswitcheroo`. It just gives me more problems. The laptop in my hands has an Intel Haswell and an AMD Radeon HD 8850M / R9 M265X.

`sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` gives:

```
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :Pwr:0000:03:00.0
```

I tried using `echo DDIS` on the file, which should normally switch to the dedicated at the next X-session start. Using `reboot`, there was no effect. Giving the command and using Logout, I only got low graphics mode error and couldn't get back to the system. Thankfully after a hard reboot things returned back to the original.

I also tried using `echo OFF` (if I can't get it to work, why leave it on). On next reboot this worked, but too efficiently. Not only the dedicated device was no more listed in `lspci`, even the switch file vanished. Not sure, if this is intentional. A bit later I somehow managed to get back to the starting point.

My aim is still the same. I would like to use the dedicated one and be able to switch between the two.

**Update 2**: My dedicated card uses the `radeon` kernel driver, so the problem shouldn't be related to the `amdgpu` driver being new and not supported by `vgaswitcheroo`.

**Update 3**: Haven't read it through in details, but seems to be a bug listed here: [bugs.launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1581270)
At least he doesn't get black screen like me whenever trying.

Comment: I have the same things, and I've given up. I can manually switch the "switchable graphics" off in BIOS. Every script I've tried somehow caused other problems, like overheating CPU and such. I'll be following this question closely, should there be a way. But I guess we'll have to wait months before it gets a switchable script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some news.

I updated the kernel to 4.4.13. Now I don't have error messages is dmesg.
Added radeon.dpm=1 radeon.modeset=1 to /etc/default/grub file (not sure if everything is needed).

sudo update-grub and reboot

Although I still cannot switch between the cards with DDIS, but I can run specific programs with the dedicated AMD, using

```
DRI_PRIME=1 programpathname
```

command in Terminal. That is already quite good, because I don't need the dedicated for browsing the web or so.

For me this is a reasonable solution and result.